# space in directory name

Tags: r

I am trying to read a text file located in following paths. I am getting error if I read the file from long directory..  But if I place the file right under C, it runs fine. Could anyone tell me how to read table from following directory path ?

```
> data1 <-read.table("C:\\Documents and Settings Administrator\\My Documents\\My Dropbox\\data1.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE) 
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection 
In addition: Warning message: 
In file(file, "rt") : 
  cannot open file 'C:\Documents and Settings Administrator\My Documents\My Dropbox\data.txt': No such file or directory 
> data1 <-read.table("C:\\data1.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE) 
>
```

Comment: Are you sure the directory is "Documents and Settings Administrator" and not, "Documents and Settings\Administrator"? The latter is standard.

Comment: Under console you could use paths completion. Write `"C:/Doc` and press Tab. It should extend to `"C:/Documents and Settings/`.

Answer (score 5):

You are almost certainly missing a separator in

```
C:\\Documents and Settings Administrator\\My Documents\\My Dropbox\\data1.txt
```

It should read

```
C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\My Dropbox\\data1.txt
```

I think this, rather than the spaces, is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In R's string literals, the backslash character is used an escape character; this can be seen in your example, where `"\t"` is resolved to a tab character.  If you would like to use the blackslash itself, you should use a double backslash.

```
data1 <- read.table("C:\\Path\\To\\A\\File")
```

It's also OK to use a forward slash:

```
data1 <- read.table("C:/Path/To/A/File")
```

In addition, I would check the path carefully: in your pasted code it seems you might be missing a backslash between "Documents and Settings" and "Administrator".

In answer to your question title, there should be no problem with including spaces in a file path.

Comment: His file is a tab-delimited file, so you should be passing either `sep = '\t'` or use `read.delim()` instead of `read.table()`.  But, I agree with you.  His problem is that he left out the slash between "Documents and Settings" and "Administrator".